# Python 3, having trouble resetting variables for a login code

Tags: python, csv

I have typed this code up and it seems to work when you get the login details correct the first time

when you get the login details incorrect but then they are correct the second time, it doesn't work

here is the code:

```
login_success = 0
import csv
with open("passwords.csv") as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

while login_success == 0:
    login_username = ""
    login_password = ""
    get_password = ""
    row = ""
    login_username = input("\nEnter username: ")
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == login_username:
            get_password = row[1]
    login_password = input("\nEnter password: ")

    if str(login_password) == str(get_password):
        login_success = 1
    else:
        print("\nUsername/password is incorrect. Try Again.")
        login_success = 0
print("\n Succesfully logged in")`
```

It seems to be correct but here is a console spit out:

```
= RESTART: /Users/*****/Password new/Password.py =
returning User? || YES / NO || yes

Enter username: username1234

Enter password: password1234

 Succesfully logged in

= RESTART: /Users/*****/Password new/Password.py =
returning User? || YES / NO || yes

Enter username: wrong_username

Enter password: wrong_password

Username/password is incorrect. Try Again.

Enter username: username1234

Enter password: password1234

Username/password is incorrect. Try Again.
```

Comment: You have to reopen your file. Like this you are at the end of the file after the first try and no new lines can be read in the second iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you while loop should be like this

```
while login_success == 0:
    user_exist = 0
    login_username = ""
    login_password = ""
    get_password = ""
    row = ""
    login_username = input("\nEnter username: ")
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == login_username:
            get_password = row[1]
            login_password = input("\nEnter password: ")
            user_exist = 1
            if str(login_password) == str(get_password):
                login_success = 1
            else:
                print("\npassword is incorrect. Try Again.")
                login_success = 0

    if user_exist == 0:
        print("\nusename does not exist. Try Again.")
```